# Is it possible to upgrade more apps at once in Google play console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

we have about 50 apps in our project in Google play developer console and we would like to optimize upgrade process. When we create new version, we always have to upgrade all apps one by one.

Those apps are similar, only few images and colors are differents (apps are clones of main app).

My question is, if this is even possible? And if yes, how?

Thanks so much

Comment: Use the command line tool [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) to automate the app upload through the Google Play Store API. Afterwards, uploading and APK / AAB should be no more work than a terminal command. You can also deploy new app meta data from it (screenshots, text).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can automate color and image changes through a simple plain Java/Kotlin
   class.
2. Clean and generate release build for new application programmatically.
3. Finally once you complete above steps and you get a release build refer below
   link to automate apk/bundle upload.

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.apks/upload

Even you can do coding in plain Java/Kotlin for upgrading apk/bundle to Google Play console.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but is it also aplicable to signed .AAB? We are doing Generate signed AAB bundle in Android Studio.

Comment: Yes, you can refer below link for AAB,https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.bundles/upload

Comment: And what about iOS, is this also possible with iOS apps somehow?

Comment: No idea on IOS.